# Why is variable inside callback function undefined outside of it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is `eventFB1` `undefined` outside of the `graph.get` callback function?

And why is the `eventFB` object different to response I get for `res` (e.g. in the console log as `eventFB1`) inside of the `graph.get` callback function?

```
var graph = require('fbgraph');

var eventFB = graph.get('13216634559578/posts', {limit: 1, access_token: 34ul345kt39884p'},
                function(err, res) {
                    var eventFB1 = res;
                    console.log(eventFB1);
                });

console.log(eventFB1);
```

Thanks!

Comment: it's `undefined` because of async callback. You are getting `res` later then printing `console.log(eventFB1)` outside of the `graph.get`

Comment: eventFB1 is undefined oustide, because it is defined inside the function. the scope is not global. To be accesed outside, it must be declared as a global variable.Could you please make a codepen with the code? i tried but it says require and graph is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `graph.get` is an **asynchronous** request whereas javascript is a **synchronous** execution.

Therefore, your code outside the get call executes before you get the response from the request